# Xcode 14.3: App built is not able to open on iOS 13.7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

Environment: iOS 13.5.1 or 13.6.1 (we received report from these 2 version) Device: iPhone 7 Plus (received 2 reports only come from this device).

help!!!

Comment: rebuild with Xcode 14.2

Comment: Developer Forums:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727611

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727680